# Angular-ui-calendar with require error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

im trying to use angular-ui-calendar in my angularjs page with require library. 
I put angular-ui-calendar in bower.json, and install it.
Now on my main module i write this (Thera are more libraries, but i ommited it in the example:

```
(function (require) {
    "use strict";
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'angular': '../../../bower_components/angular/angular',
            'angular-ui-calendar': '../../../bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar'

        },
        shim: {
            'angular': { deps: [], exports: 'angular' },
            'angular-ui-calendar': {deps: ['angular', 'bootstrap']}
        }
    });

    require([
        "angular", "angular-route", "angular-resource", "angular-sanitize", "angular-moment",
        "jquery", "bootstrap", "app",
        "moment", "moment-es", "abn_tree_directive", "underscore", "ui-utils", "jspdf", "angular-ui-calendar"
    ], function (angular) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
}(require));
```

Now, in my angularjs controller i put

```
var bill = angular.module("bill", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "directives",'ui.calendar']);
```

And in the web i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.changeWatcher.getTokens (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:86:36)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12243:40)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8204:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8412:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8351:11) angular.js:9778
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at allEvents (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:54:41)
    at Object.changeWatcher.getTokens (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:84:57)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12243:40)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8204:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8412:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8351:11) angular.js:9778
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.link.scope.init (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:226:26)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:262:19)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12251:29)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8204:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8412:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8351:11) angular.js:9778
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.changeWatcher.getTokens (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:86:36)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12243:40)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8204:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8412:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8351:11) angular.js:9778
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at allEvents (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:54:41)
    at Object.changeWatcher.getTokens (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:84:57)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12243:40)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12516:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8204:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8412:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8351:11)
```

And the calendar dont show..Need i to put the dependencies in the main.js to load it with require o do it itself? Anyone knows whats wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same problem 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at allEvents'. Can you guide me on how to get around this?